# Resolving MVC Controller with WindsorControllerFactory

Tags: model-view-controller, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I'm new to Windsor, so

Here is my installer:

```
public class ControllersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(FindControllers().Configure(ConfigureControllers()));
    }

    private ConfigureDelegate ConfigureControllers()
    {
        return c => c.LifeStyle.Transient;
    }

    private BasedOnDescriptor FindControllers()
    {
        return AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
            .BasedOn<IController>()
            .If(Component.IsInSameNamespaceAs<HomeController>())
            .If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"));
    }
}
```

And factory:

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        _kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        try
        {
            if (controllerType == null)
            {
                throw new HttpException(404,
                    string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.",
                    requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
            }
            return (IController) _kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

All controllers which inherits from Controller are resolved well. But when I try to instantiate something like this:

```
public class ArticleController : RestController<Article>
{
    protected override JsonResult Create(Article item)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

RestController also inherits from Controller

it throws
**The IControllerFactory 'TheStorage.Web.Factories.WindsorControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Article'**

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried a BasedOn<RestController> to your FindControllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is due to the try/catch that you put in the factory. You should not be doing that.

Now, what is happening most likely, is your container can not resolve your controller, likely either because it has unresolvable dependencies, or it doesn't get registered (maybe you put it in wrong namespace)?

Once you let it fail, Windsor will tell you exactly what the problem is.